# Adding logging to an asp.net Dynamic Data application

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, dynamic-data

I am trying to find out what would be the best way to add logging to a Dynamic Data app?
I am using DD for an admin interface and I need to log all the actions the user makes.
I thought of adding things to the codebehind of the PageTemplates\ListDetails for example, but was wondering if there is a better way... 
For data access I am using Entity Framework with Sqlite.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your user info added to the audit trail you could do one of two things:

1. Use SPROCS in your DB to do CRUD operations and passin the user info
2. Add business logic in the form of Partial Classes to your model

See links:
[How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes (Entity Framework)](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=10&checkda=1&ct=1240388641&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc716714.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354)
[How to Map Stored Procedures using the ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/09/14/how-to-map-stored-procedures-using-the-ado-net-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Enterprise Library Logging Block.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/GetLoggingWithEntLib.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309506.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see how this would help, it's just a logging framework? Or am I missing something? The problem is not in logging, I  am using log4net otherwise, it's how and where to instrument DynamicData to be able to log.